# Jenkins and mock on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, fedora, chroot

We use a physical server for our Jenkins build system at the moment and I am looking into the feasibility of moving it to AWS. The build jobs are script executions and the key aspect is that those scripts launch various Fedora mock shells and execute scripts within those to perform build steps. For various reasons, I can't avoid the Fedora mocks.

Is it possible to replicate these Jenkins jobs on AWS? To my mind, the mock element is the blocker, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You can pretty easily run [Fedora on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-doqa62vonqvo6) if that's your concern.

Comment: Fedora is incidental really, it's executing scripts in a mock that's required.